# How to deploy an upgradable erc20 properly

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, contract-upgrading

I have a simple ERC20Upgradable:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/ERC20Upgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol";

contract GovernanceToken is Initializable, ERC20Upgradeable, OwnableUpgradeable, UUPSUpgradeable {
    /// @custom:oz-upgrades-unsafe-allow constructor
    constructor() {
        _disableInitializers();
    }

    function initialize() initializer public {
        __ERC20_init("Governance Token", "GT");
        __Ownable_init();
        __UUPSUpgradeable_init();

        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }

    function _authorizeUpgrade(address newImplementation)
        internal
        onlyOwner
        override
    {}
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to deploy this properly. I was using my old deployment script but it seems to fail.

```
const { getNamedAccounts, deployments, network } = hre
const { deploy, log } = deployments
const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()

const governanceTokenResult = await deploy(GOVERNANCE_TOKEN_NAME, {
  from: deployer,
  args: [],
  log: true,
  // we need to wait if on a live network so we can verify properly
  waitConfirmations: networkConfig[network.name].blockConfirmations || 1,
})

if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
  await verify(governanceTokenResult.address, [], "contracts/GovernanceToken.sol:GovernanceToken")
}

const governanceToken = await ethers.getContractAt(GOVERNANCE_TOKEN_NAME, governanceTokenResult.address);

const name = await governanceToken.name();
log(`name: ${name}`);
```

I tried the contract compiles and deploys however, I just calling name after to verify it worked properly, but nothing is returned.   I tried to manually call initialize but it seems to automatically get called when deploying the token.

how can I deploy an upgradable tokens?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades